# MYSQL LOAD DATA IN FILE and get LAST_INSERT_ID and INSERT DATA into Another table

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I'm trying to kill multiple birds with 1 stone so to speak. I am using windows commandline mysql.exe to load local infile called from another program that I'm using and I have found there is 3 other tables that need to be updated and they use an auto incremented PK from the main table. table names are case_info, mitigation, and  processing. FIELD NAMES in case_info are case_id, **client_id**, sales_data, expenses_data, and income_data.  FIELD NAMES in mitigation are mit_id, **client_id**, and mitigation_data.
FIELD NAMES in processing are proc_id, **client_id**, and processing_data. 
The command I am passing to the cli

```
mysql.exe -uUSER -pSOMEPASSWORD -hEXAMPLE.COM TABLENAME  -e \"load data local infile '" +leads+ "' 
into table clients 
fields terminated by ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(first_name,address,city,state,zip,saledate,file_id,last_updated,last_updated_by);"+ chr(34)`
```

The **client_id** is AI,PK so I need to run an insert statement on the 3 tables listed above to insert text into the *_data fields and the **client_id** field on all of the 3 tables while doing the load data local infile after each record is loaded. Im not sure if that is possible or not if it isn't can someone help me craft a query to run all at once or to run after the load to get the **client_id** from clients table where it's not found on the other tables to be updated and insert the data?  The data to be loaded into the other tables is the same for every record to start and updated from the main app.

Comment: Seems like writing a script to do this would be a more productive route to a solution. What programming language do you have access to

Comment: load your data in a temporary table and use standard sql to fill the other tables from that temporary table

Comment: I know a little python but for me to write something like that into python would take a few weeks if not months.  I have python and ruby installed to run scripts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After messing around for a few hours I was able to come up with a workable solution sloppy as it may be here it is.  I tested it on temp tables.  I did have to edit the DEFAULT value of the fields with the data which once the client_id is inserted it's fills the default value and solves my problem.

```
import mysql.connector
import pymysql
import sys
pathto = easygui.fileopenbox()
db = mysql.connector.connect(host='HOSTNAME', user='USER', passwd='PASSWORD', db='DATABASE')
mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute("select max(client_id) from c_temp")
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
maxid = str(myresult).replace('(','')
maxid = maxid.replace(',','')
maxid = maxid.replace(')','')
path = pathto.replace('\\','/')
if maxid =='None':
    print('NO MAX ID FOUND')
    maxid = str(0)
print(maxid)
print(path)
#import leads
def csv_to_mysql(load_sql, host, user, password):
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                user=user,
                                password=password,
                                autocommit=True,
                                local_infile=1)
        print('Connected to DB: {}'.format(host))
        # Create cursor and execute Load SQL
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(load_sql)
        print('Successfully loaded the table from csv.')
        con.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)

# Execution Example
load_sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+path+"' INTO TABLE hometrust.c_temp\
 fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'(first_name,address,city,state,zip,saledate,file_id);"
host = 'HOSTNAME'
user = 'USER'
password = 'PASSWORD'
csv_to_mysql(load_sql, host, user, password)

db.autocommit=False
try:
 mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO case_temp (client_id) SELECT client_id FROM c_temp WHERE client_id >"+maxid+";")
 mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO mit_temp (client_id) SELECT client_id FROM c_temp WHERE client_id >"+maxid+";")
 mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO proc_temp (client_id) SELECT client_id FROM c_temp WHERE client_id >"+maxid+";")
 db.commit()
except:
 db.rollback()
```

Answer (score 3):

Start a transaction before loading the records from the file. Then you can save the old `MAX(client_id)` and use that in a queries that find all the new IDs that were created in the main table, and adds them to the other tables.

```
mysql ... -e \"
START TRANSACTION;
SET @maxid = (select max(client_id) from clients;
load data local infile '" +leads+ "' 
into table clients 
fields terminated by ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(first_name,address,city,state,zip,saledate,file_id,last_updated,last_updated_by);
INSERT INTO case_info (client_id)
SELECT client_id FROM client
WHERE client_id > @maxid;
INSERT INTO mitigation (client_id)
SELECT client_id FROM client
WHERE client_id > @maxid;
INSERT INTO processing (client_id)
SELECT client_id FROM client
WHERE client_id > @maxid;
COMMIT
"+ chr(34)`
```

The other three `INSERT` queries assume that there are appropriate defaults for the other columns -- you can add explicit values for them if needed.

Comment: Sorry I should have posted what the actual query to the cli looked like with the variables in place,  `mysql.exe -uUSER -pSOMEPASSWORD -hEXAMPLE.COM TABLENAME  -e "load data local infile 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/karen/1205/brockrdy.csv' into table clients fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'(first_name,address,city,state,zip,saledate,file_id,last_updated,last_updated`  that is with a file selected

Comment: After stepping away for a moment and thinking about it I may be able to do this in a python script easier than I originally thought.  You gave me the steps needed in the transaction so i'm off to play with it and see what kind of damage I can do.  I will post back my results.